# Why is a linear gradient working for my div, but not for my body?

Tags: css

I'm testing out some CSS hover effects and I've made a linear gradient appear on the background of my container div which holds an unordered list. I've applied another linear gradient to `body` to give the page a different background. For some reason the gradient on `body` is not working, and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #480048, #c04848);
  font-family: 'Lato';
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 1200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/simonrevill/pen/zaNYBB

Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't realise this question had already been asked, sorry. Thanks for the link to your extensive explanation!

Comment: well, don't be sorry ;) not easy to find such precise question .. even me it took me time to find it

Answer (score 0):

That's due to `position: absolute` on your `.container` element: With that, your `body` has a height of zero (since absolutely positioned elements are not considered concerning the size/height of the parent element), i.e. it's not visible.

Just change the `position` setting, for example to `relative` and you'll see the gradient on the body

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzgxep

Comment: I would say the explanation is not totally exact ... because if you change the gradient with an image it will show due to background propagation, but with gradient it's different because of the height:0 ... so yes it's about the height:0 but not only this.

Answer (score -2):

The body has no inline content. Add *anything* to the body, such as:

```
<body>&nbsp;
```

and it will then render the body background.